# how to automatic create and autoscale network?

Tags: automation

is there any software or python library that can automatic create and autoscale physical network such as for cisco switches or automatic create a set of cisco configs which can form a network?

is it the same principle with openstack Murano?

there are many topology, how do it choose which topology to use to create network?

Comment: This question really is too broad for asking on Stack Exchange, entire books can be written about this subject. Also, resource recommendations are explicitly off topic here.